Windows 11 pen drawing over controls instead of interacting with them
I'm using an MPP2.0 pen (think Surface Pen) to interact with my Windows 11 device, and I'm having an issue where the entire area around text boxes and dropdown menus won't be interactable because Windows will think I'm trying to handwrite into the control instead.
So, I can't open a dropdown menu with the pen, because when I tap on it to do so, Windows decides that I'm trying to handwrite a period character. I can't tap to focus a text box with the stylus either, for the same reason, until I lift it off the display and wait for the handwriting to apply (just so that I can delete the period in order to actually type what I want).
I found a setting in the "Pen & Windows Ink" section that seems like it should cover this functionality:

However, as you can see by the screenshot, this is currently turned off, and I've rebooted multiple times since applying that change and the handwriting functionality is still blocking basic interactions with UI controls..
For example, when I try to tap to focus the text field in Discord, it just draws a useless dot like this below the text field, not actually focusing the text field:

When I try to open a dropdown menu in Krita, it does the same thing, not actually opening the dropdown:

How do I actually turn this functionality off? Did I change the wrong setting, or is there some sort of workaround I need to apply?

Could be OEM Software interfering. What device are you using ?

@1NN I'm using a clean/manual install of Windows 11 on an MS-7D97 motherboard, so there's no OEM software installed whatsoever. Especially not for anything to do with the pen, as this was a plug-and-play setup (plugging in Thunderbolt monitor with MPP pen input) and Windows Update automatic driver installs are off (plus Windows Update also having been completely disabled for the past 6 months or so, long before I ever got any pen). Aside from that, is there a way to check if any interference is happening anyway? Any registry keys I should check?

Does the pen have a side button? The pen buttons are used in several gestures - link.

go to visit Bluetooth & devices and then choose Pen & Windows Ink. In this settings menu, go down to Additional pen settings and pick Let me use my pen as a mouse when it's available.

@harrymc the pen has two side buttons, yes. I'm not pressing either one of them. Both of them work; the top one is right-click by default whereas the bottom one acts as an eraser button in apps that support it.

@1NN that setting doesn't seem to disable the writing thing, unfortunately.

Have you tried to install the HP Pen control which should work with the MPP2.0 ?

@1NN no, because it only lets you rebind the stylus buttons, it doesn't have anything to do with the handwriting feature

I have sometimes used the trick of doing a right-click on an object just in order to select it, when selecting via touch is difficult. Does that help?

@harrymc looks like neither side button prevents the pen from drawing over the dropdown instead of selecting it. :/ if I'm very precise with my tap then it'll sometimes be properly interpreted as a tap, but I'd prefer this writing feature to be completely off.

If I manually terminate the "Touch keyboard and handwriting panel" process (tabtip.exe) then this feature goes away temporarily, but of course, I use the touch keyboard occasionally, so the moment I open the touch keyboard even once, tabtip.exe is running again and the pen is drawing again. I'd love if there's some way to get tabtip.exe to stop doing this but still provide touch keyboard functionality

At least as can be seen for OneNote, Microsoft thought that only two modes exist : Text and Draw. You might need non-Microsoft drivers, and for that it's important to fully identify the pen. Try to search it in its properties in Device Manager.

@harrymc I know which pen it is, it's a UOGIC Slim Pen 2, which has many, many rebrands (such as RENAISSER Raphael Slim, which I also have). It has no drivers, and doesn't need drivers, as MPP pens are already fully supported by Windows, just like Precision Touchpad and other first-party interfaces. And even if it had drivers, I doubt those drivers would be able to tell tabtip.exe to shut up with the handwriting recognition, that is most likely a system-wide thing that I need to figure out how to configure explicitly...

For disabling handwriting try these methods.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You may try to update the pen firmware by following the Microsoft article
Update pen firmware on Surface Hub.
If that doesn't help, then this might be a conceptual problem on the
side of Microsoft.
In at least one article for
Switch between drawing and text mode in Microsoft OneNote
we see that only two modes exist for Microsoft : Text and Draw.
You'll need to work around that with tricks.
My favorite trick when faced with a difficult touch interface, is to use
the right-click to select the object and then Escape out of the context
menu. This leaves the object as selected and it's then more responsive.
Sometimes even the context menu contains the action that I'm trying
to provoke.
A strong-arm method is to disable the Windows component
TabTip.exe, which is the Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel
process for using handwriting input, for converting text to symbols,
and more functions.
Doing that is a workaround and not a solution, so can be used
when necessary and until a better solution is found.
There are three methods for that listed in the article
TabTip.exe: What Is It & How to Disable It:

Kill the process TabTip.exe
Disable from
Settings > Bluetooth & devices > Pen & Windows Ink
the option for
"Use your handwriting to enter text"
Disable the Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel system service
from services.msc.


There's nothing wrong with the pen firmware, it interacts correctly with the digitizer. Moreover this pen doesn't have updatable firmware, and shouldn't as MPP2.0 doesn't include any handwriting features natively, it's implemented in software by Windows 11.

Alternative interaction methods which were included in various articles: (1) Use a long press of the object, (2) Press the object and while pressing tap the screen, (3) Draw a circle around the object. (Microsoft's pen software was bad and has grown worse over the years.)


This only works if I manage to keep the pen perfectly still on my frictionless glass screen. I could add a matte or paper-like screen protector but this would affect the clarity of the OLED. 2. All touches are ignored while the pen is near the screen, just tested it. 3. Drawing a circle around the object, for text fields, just inputs a smiley face emoji.


Microsoft really made it difficult. Do you manage to Use the pen menu?

yes, the pen menu shows up once I've used my pen at least once.

Does it help in entering another mode than draw or text?

"Draw" and "text" don't exist. They are not a thing. Those are application features of OneNote, not Windows or Windows Ink

@Dev: Note that your answer about disabling tabtips.exe was first suggested by me in a comment, but you rejected it. You should have told me you decided to accept it and I would have included it in my answer.

@Dev My philosophy is to always honor those who spend their free time and passion to try to solve my issues. But of course, everyone is free to apply their standards and conceiving.

@harrymc I rejected it at the time because I was under the impression that there should be another solution that doesn't involve disabling the entire input subsystem but since nobody seems to know if that exists I decided having this disabled is more valuable than being able to use my computer without a keyboard. I would still prefer for the touch keyboard to still work but oh well.

@Dev: I recommended in our chat to have a look at the article TabTip.exe: What Is It & How to Disable It, where Method 1 touches directly on your solution and Methods 2-3 are alternatives. All of them can be done and undone easily.

@harrymc Like I said I didn't want to accept that solution unless there were no alternatives, I was still looking for alternatives at the time. If you want to link that article as part of your answer (clarifying that it's a temporary workaround until a real solution is discovered) then I can accept it instead as a workaround. I just didn't want to accept an answer that doesn't actually contain the info I ended up using.

@Dev: No problem - I added this into my answer.

@harrymc OK, bountied you then. sorry for being so difficult, I'm not particularly happy with anything right now but at least disabling tabtip.exe is the least wrong out of everything that's been proposed so far.

It's worth noting also that TabTip.exe will restart itself automatically every time pen or touch is used, so the only way to keep it disabled is to either suspend the process without killing it, or do something like rename the executable so it can't ever start. Suspending the process however causes shell windows (such as Open dialogs) to stop working properly, so renaming the executable and then killing the existing process has worked the best for me, even though it does also disable automatic activation of the on-screen keyboard (it can still be brought up manually from the taskbar though)

Since this is a Windows 11 feature which is documented to work (second link), there are two possible causes for the issue:

a bug in Windows 11
a non-compliant / non-supported hardware

Given that the OP has written in a comment:

Windows Update automatic driver installs are off (plus Windows Update
also having been completely disabled for the past 6 months or so, long
before I ever got any pen)

the first thing to do is to test the hardware on a fully updated machine. Besides bugfixes, Microsoft is still adding support for older or less-used hardware to Windows 11 through its updates. So a simple driver or feature update might fix the issue. Also, in the above links is mentioned that the pen features are about to be expanded under Windows 11, so they are under active development and (might) need Windows updates to be turned on in order to work as intended.
Should the hardware not work on a fully updated system, contact the OEM of your Screen/Pen. If the hardware was advertised to support Windows 11, the issue is covered by legal warranty in almost all countries worldwide. Unfortunately not all OEMs are equally reactive, but try your luck.
Otherwise, if Windows 11 support is not explicitly given, try to test the hardware on a Windows 10 system. I own a laptop with a pen which is 'eligible' for update to Windows 11, but my OEM has advised me not to do so because of possible issues with the pen. Some hardware is still waiting to be supported on Windows 11.

Updating my machine doesn't seem to fix the issue. The handwriting feature is technically working as intended, I just can't seem to turn it off. Both links you provided don't describe the issue I'm facing and seem to completely miss "what I'm asking, which is to turn off the handwriting input into text boxes. It has nothing to do with using the pen as a cursor, that option only controls whether the mouse cursor moves with the pen tip or not.

@Dev I'm sorry that didn't help. If yours is also a touch screen, maybe you'll need to turn off touch when using the pen. https://www.elevenforum.com/t/enable-or-disable-ignore-touch-input-when-using-pen-in-windows-11.5680/

Also, are you sure there is no specific driver available for your device? Even if it is plug and play, sometimes the standard windows driver just won't do the job. I understand the pen is standard, but maybe the screen or pen-screen combination needs something more

Touch is already off when I'm using the pen, in fact I'm unable to change that (the "Ignore touch input when I'm using my pen" setting doesn't actually seem to work). As for drivers, I'm using an INNOCN PU15-PRE monitor which just connects over Thunderbolt, and as far as I can tell there's no driver available because everything is standard. There's no driver for the pen because it doesn't connect to the computer at all, except for over Bluetooth sometimes but that's just for the top button, not required or involved at all with actual pen input.

@Dev Given that your screen basically costs half-a-laptop, I'd definitively contact support. If they don't react, leave a one-star rating wherever you bought it: that usually wakes up a sleeping dog.

There's nothing wrong with the screen.

+1. Reciprocal upvote. Thanks.

This handwriting feature seems to be controlled by TabTip.exe which can be suspended (using a tool like Process Hacker) to prevent it from blocking pen input. However, this process also seems to control IME and automatic activation of the On-Screen Keyboard (though it can still be brought up manually if you have the taskbar icon for it enabled), so those features also won't work when it's suspended.
This is not an ideal solution because I do like the on-screen keyboard but suspending TabTip.exe does actually manage to disable this feature when nothing else (no settings, no registry keys, etc) seems to work.
I would prefer basically any other solution though, but there don't seem to be any yet.

found this thread which has a script to toggle TabTip.exe on or off. Might be useful for your case.

@1NN I just renamed the executable to reversibly prevent it from starting, but I would prefer basically any other solution because I like the on-screen keyboard. None of the other answers solve my problem (I think they both completely misunderstand it), so it'd be inappropriate to give them any of the bounty

If this does not solve your problem, don't mark it as correct answer. This doesn't make any sense.

@1NN It solves my problem just fine. It just causes another one too...
